# Hyperparameter Tuning on Logistic Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I was building a **classification model** on predicting water quality.
I intend to do ***Hyper-parameter tuning*** for the **Logistic Regression** model.
**Here is the code**..

params =

```
     [{'Penalty':['l1','l2','elasticnet','none'],
       
      'Solver':['liblinear']}]
      
     grid= GridSearchCV(estimator=LogisticRegression(),param_grid=params,cv=10,scoring='f1_macro')
```

**But i am getting this error**

ValueError: Invalid parameter Penalty for estimator LogisticRegression(). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

~~Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.. Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

Check at [Logistic Regression doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). You've define `params = {"Penalty"...` and the parameter is `penalty` with lowercase **p**. Probably you'll have to check the `Solver` hyper parameter too...